# Shared User Certificates Required for Application but disallowed in Store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, nfc

I have written a simple UWP application to play media triggered by RFID tags. This function requires the Shared User Certificates capability to be enabled to connect to the card reader using:

```
smartCardReader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
```

If I remove this capability I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException (Access is denied).

When I run the application certification I get:

```
   Warning: The app has declared the following special use capabilities: 
   *The app has declared the sharedUserCertificates capability.*   
   Impact if not fixed: If you don’t have a company account with the Windows Store, you won’t be able to upload this app.
```

As I have no company account it means that I cannot upload this application to the store for private distribution. Is there anything I can do to work around this limitation besides side-loading this application onto the required machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to work around this limitation besides
>   side-loading this application onto the required machines?

For private distribution, [Hockey App](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-sideload-uwp-applications) can be an option if you're not able to upload the Store submission.

It still makes your app installed onto user's machine via sideloading. But it can be convenient for your distribution and it can help to collect crash report as well as get feedback from users.